# Parâmetro Not null nos campos Int

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp, scaffold

Estou criando uma aplicação em Asp.NET MVC (Estou utilizando o recurso Scafffolded), porém, todos os campos inteiros estão sendo obrigatório o seu preenchimento, como removo este parâmetro?

Obs: Já tentei desmarcar a opção "Permitir valor nulo" no banco de dados, porém sem sucesso.

Estou achando que esta validação está ocorrendo no `.cshtml`, porém não localizei.

Modelo.

```
public class prospectModel 
{ 
    public int id { get; set; } 
    public string contato { get; set; } 
    public string nomeRazaoSocial { get; set; } 
    public int documento { get; set; } 
    public int telefone { get; set; } 
    public int celular { get; set; } 
    public string email { get; set; } 
    public string anotacoes { get; set; } 
}
```

cshtml

```
<div class="form-group"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.celular, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }) 
    <div class="col-md-10"> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.celular, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.celular, "", new { @ class = "text-danger" })
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Como está seu model? As propriedades estão como `Required`?

Comment: Isso depende, o html ele preenche como required default apenas alguns tipos de dados ... como por exemplo type: number ... o seu .cshtml está como ?

Comment: Não está como Required :(

Comment: Edite sua resposta, não fique pode código nos comentários que a visualização fica péssima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como inteiro é um tipo primitivo ele não permite valores nulos, no seu caso ele deve aceitar, ou seja você deve marcar essa propriedade como [nullable](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) no seu view model:

```
public int? Idade {get; set; }
```

Comment: Coloquei o "?", atualizei o banco de dados, e compilei, e deu certo! Obrigado =D